# Set Auto Refresh Page on Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have 3 different page on my angular (im using Angular 6), but im still confusing how to make all of my pages auto refresh/reload with interval time.

Is there any way to make function or etc ? relate to auto refresh/reload in each of page component.ts, component.html, or maybe in app-routing.module ?

Any suggestion or experience to make something like that ?

For example component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-example-page',
 templateUrl: './example-page.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./example-page.component.less']
})
export class ExamplePageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to refresh your page? Do you want to update in your template?

Comment: i want to update data that store from database man @MBDev

Comment: Why cant you use the following design: a service fetches data from the DB, you call that service in your component - so instead of the whole component being loaded, you update the relevant sections which depend on the data from the service

Comment: can you give me example how a service fetches data from the DB with real time update ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Example

```
import { Observable, interval, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class YourComponent ... {

  private updateSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.updateSubscription = interval(1000).subscribe(
        (val) => { this.updateStats()
      }
  );



}
```

Comment: Hint: You need to import rsjx observable

Comment: I have been exploring around signalR approach for this but this was a pure simple and made my need so easy.